# Vizualize unsigned char * array as bitmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, bitmap, visualization

I want to visualize an in-memory `unsigned char *` array as a bitmap. I'm using Visual Studio and unmanaged C++ code (specifically, C++ in a UE4 application).

I found the [ImageWatch Visual Studio vizualiser plugin](http://opencv.org/image-watch-plugin-for-visual-studio.html). This is close to what I'm looking for, however;

- The plugin only supports up to VS2015 - it doesn't work with VS2017
- It seems the maintainer has moved on to other projects or another employer
- Although this plugin supports extensibility via specifying visualizers for new image struct formats, I want to vizualise a raw array by manually specifying the width, height, pixel format etc. As far as I can tell, this plugin doesn't support this.

I would try updating ImageWatch to add the features I need and to work with VS2017, but it's closed source.

Does anyone know of a similar tool?

Comment: Wrong place to ask this, I'm afraid, but looks like a good fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . I'd delete this question and ask there.

Comment: I do not understand - new image format definition supported by the plug-in consists of width, height, pixel format... How it is different from your image type definition? https://imagewatch.azurewebsites.net/ImageWatchHelp/ImageWatchHelp.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is the Visual Studio 2017 Image Visualizer here: https://github.com/Jaex/ImageVisualizer, maybe it could help you as a workaround.

In addition, no Image Watch plugin for VS 2017 now, actually  other community members also submitted the feature request to product team here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18936751-update-image-watch-for-2017

If possible, you could also vote and add your comment for this feature request.